# Trying to use setClass to pass a train function from caret of type "train"

Tags: r, r-caret, r-s4

I am attempting to use custom class builder setClass() to return results from a train function (caret package).

```
setClass(Class="TrainResults",
         representation(
                 successrate="numeric",
                 plsFit="train"
         )
)
```

This is how I create TrainResults in my function:

```
    return(new("Trainresults",
               successrate=successrate,
               plsFit=plsFit))
```

"successrate" works fine as it is of numeric type, but plsFit (of type train {caret}) complains that:

```
Error in validObject(.Object) : 
   invalid class “Trainresults” object: undefined class for slot "plsFit" ("train")
```

Any idea how to get it to pass the object of type train properly? Thanks!

Comment: Have you run `require(caret)` or `library("caret")`?

Comment: Yes, I have. I should add that when I simply return plsFit from my function, everything works so the problem isn't with the plsFit object but with the way I am initializing the setClass (I think). thanks!

Comment: When you return the `plsFit` object and call `class()` on it, what is returned?

Comment: it return type "train"; BrodieG is correct, it looks like an S3-S4 issue. Thanks for looking it this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the return value of `caret::train` is not an S4 object, rather an S3 object. Use `setOldClass("train")`, which should then register the `train` class for use with S4 slots.  This works:

```
setOldClass("train")
trn <- train(data.frame(x=1:3, y=1:3), 1:3)
isS4(trn)
# [1] FALSE
new("TrainResults", successrate=1, plsFit=trn)
# An object of class "TrainResults"
# ... omitted a bunch of output
```

The basic data types (e.g. `numeric`, etc.) are all already pre-registered as S4 classes so you don't need to do that for those to work as S4 slots.

Note you have a typo in your code as well (lower case R in `Train*r*esulsts`).